# XML Declaration Tag using SimpleXML

Tags: java, xml

I'm starting to use the Simple XML framework with annotations ([link](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#namesoace)) for Java, but I don't get, how to prelude the XML declaration tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` in the XML file. So my question is: How do I get the XML declaration as first tag?

```
package simplexml;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class Example {

    @Element
    private String text;

    @Attribute
    private int index;

    public Example(String text, int index) {
        this.text = text;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return text;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        Example example = new Example("Example message", 123);
        File result = new File("example.xml");

        try {
            serializer.write(example, result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Produces:

```
<example index="123">
   <text>Example message</text>
</example>
```

What I'd like to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<example index="123">
   <text>Example message</text>
</example>
```

Thanks! Also, where could I look such things up?

Comment: That version and encoding are (more or less) the default values. Why do you want to be explicit?

Comment: True, but: "XML declaration is a processing instruction that identifies the document as being XML. All XML documents should begin with an XML declaration." [link](http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml)

Comment: I don't think that is a very good source … but [the specification agrees](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd)

Comment: Look at the JavaDoc for Persister and Format. That looks like the way to do it.

Comment: Ok, it's really that simple, thanks to Quentin for the hint to look at Format and Persister:

 `Format format = new Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>");
 Serializer serializer = new Persister(format);`

Produces the desired output.

Comment: Just one simple correction, Although `<?xml` identifies the document as being XML, but it is not a processing instruction.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use Spring for Android to send XML requests, and was facing the same problem.  Here's the code to get it work based on @implicit_knowledge's solution in case anyone needs it.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();             
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());              
Serializer serializer = new Persister(new Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>"));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter(serializer));
restTemplate.postForObject(URL, udata, String.class);
```