# SimpleXML not printing XML declaration

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm created a dynamically generated XML document with SimpleXML in PHP7.

The issue I'm facing is that the XML is not being produced with the XML declaration - and I've tried various methods unsuccessfully of doing it - currently I have the following:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><urlset />');

//more code

header('Content-Type: application/xml');

echo($xml->asXML());
```

The XML declaration should be this, at the top of the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I've also tried sketchy things like printing the declaration before the XML - to no avail.

If you need more info please let me know!

Related question = [XML Declaration Tag using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951223/xml-declaration-tag-using-simplexml)

Comment: Your code generates an XML declaration. Are you viewing this in a browser, then take a look at the page source, or try on CLI.

Comment: Yep in browser, will take a look at CLI. Thanks

Comment: Rule out the possibility that your problem is somewhere other than PHP: create an XML file in a text editor that has the declaration in it, and load that in your browser. If you don't see the declaration, it's just because your browser is hiding it. Or, put another way - don't trust your browser's view!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser was hiding it :(

To verify, save the XML to file and run `cat file.xml` in a terminal.